# Тернарная связь в MC Access - MS Access

Tags: access, связи

Приветствую.

Есть таблица. Есть поле. Как создать ему тернарную связь. 
Пример: Таблица есть, есть Поле. Допустим в поле Сотрудники есть 2 человека, которые женаты. Нужно сделать тернарную связь от поля Сотрудники в поле Сотрудники. Помогите. 
Или ссылку киньте.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тернарные связи, или многосторонние связи, или связи высокого порядка (не путать с тернарными операторами) разрешаются похожим образом, как и связи многие-ко-многим. В связи М-М участвуют только 2 таблицы сущностей, а в многосторонних - более 2-х. Т.е. просто создается промежуточная таблица, содержащая первичные ключи всех сущностей и код признака связи. В вашем описании типичная связь М-М, т.к. участвуют только 2 сущности - сотрудники, вы хотите описать их родственные связи. Добавляете в новую таблицу 2 ссылки на таблицу сотрудников и степень родства, получаем двустороннюю связь многие-ко-многим.

Чтобы связь стала многосторонней, нужна по крайней мере еще одна сущность, например отдел, в котором работают сотрудники. Добавляете в таблицу связей еще ссылку на таблицу отделов, получаем многостороннюю связь. В справочник типов связей также нужно будет добавить типы связей людей с отделами в добавок к типам связей между людьми. [Вот здесь](https://books.google.de/books?id=QjXBwtjDQgEC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=66_A4kN5qm&sig=SVOfYjwBJARzkLkh12DQvClKLO0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyo_rGmqzQAhXIrY8KHYNEAwgQ6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C&f=false), например, показан пример многосторонней связи на примере заправки.